# SharePoint 2013 RESTful calls returning 404 not found

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Using the [Get started with the SharePoint 2013 REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142380.aspx), I am trying to access the following internal SharePoint site:
http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/sites/SuperSecret/default.aspx

I have tried sending a GET request to the following URLs:

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/sites/SuperSecret/_api/SuperSecret

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/sites/SuperSecret/_api/web

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/SuperSecret/_api/SuperSecret

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/SuperSecret/_api/web

Everytime the server responds with a 404, this leads me to believe I am crafting the URL wrong.  Can someone take a look at the URL and recommend what the correct version might be.

Note:  I have not "enabled" any type REST feature since I was not the one who originally set it up, so this might also be the case if the feature needs to be enabled.

Comment: What about authentication? Is it completely open?

Comment: Also try /lists at he end of the second one.

Comment: I need to login, so what I was doing was logging in normally and then using that session and manually crafting the GET with a Chrome plugin.

/lists did not work, still 404

Answer (score 0):

http://mycs.nce.dirc.aon/sites/SuperSecret/_api/web would be an example of a valid web services url in your case and it should be possible to browse to it normally as a test.

That url should return an XML response with schema information.  If it is coming back 404 then I would attempt to call the _api/web from your top level site collection.

I am not aware of anyway to activate or deactivate REST in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue, then I realized my library which I was making REST call had too many columns, lookups and long column name.

I tried creating a new list and making a rest call which worked. 
SharePoint is really strange!